# Listening to a tcp port in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sockets

I need to listen to a  TCP port and collect the binary data from the port in my iphone how this could be done . I had searched a lot for the same but did not find anything worth, please help me any links, or sample code be greatly appretiated

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server ?

Comment: Can you accept any answer?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do is open a socket, you have two options:

Create the socket in pure C:
[Sockets in C](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

Or use the classes that Apple provides to work with sockets:

[Introduction to Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188-SW1)

If you are going to do something simple, the first option is the easiest

Answer (score 2):

There is a very useful socket library called GCDAsyncSocket on github that can be used to make both TCP/UDP sockets and comes with delegate methods for reading and writing data

[GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)